# I have a jQuery toggle function that hides and shows a 'p' tag. When there are multiple tags, toggle the specific one the user clicks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I have a jQuery function that toggles a hide and show for a [p](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag. In my HTML, it brings multiple different *store.IDs* in the results. There are specific *p* tags in the search for each store ID and I just want it to show/hide the specific one the user clicks. When I run this, all the *p* tags for all the stores showing toggle hide and show, not the specific one the user clicks. Is there a way to make it specific to the users click?

```
HTML:

<div>
    <a class="store-detail-link" href="${URLUtils.url('Stores-Details', 'storeID', store.ID)}">
        Details
    </a>
    <p class="${store.ID} test"></p>
</div>

JS:

$('.test').toggle();
```

The user will get multiple store IDs results. They should be able to toggle the "Details" button on the specific store ID they click, not all the "Details" that get shown.

Comment: Where is your JS event?  Where is your attempt to find the closest `<p>` to the toggle element?

Comment: Before more answers pop on this problem, could you explain what's the purpose of an Anchor with `href` - when you actually desire something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

To make the toggle functionality specific to the user's click on the store-detail-link element, you need to modify your jQuery code. Here's an updated version that should achieve the desired behavior:

```js
$('.store-detail-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior

    var $target = $(this).next('.test'); // Find the corresponding p tag

    $target.toggle(); // Toggle the visibility of the p tag
});
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="store-detail-link" href="${URLUtils.url('Stores-Details', 'storeID', store.ID)}">
        Details
    </a>
    <p class="${store.ID} test"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when there are multiple `a` and `p` elements as the OP says there will be?

Comment: Using `e.preventDefault();` makes an Anchor useless (even though it has the `href ` pretty  intentionally well populated) - don't you think?! If you agree, why don't ask OP for clarification?

Comment: Add more <div> blocks with <a> and <p> elements as needed

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.store-detail-link').click(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent(); // Get the parent div element
        var $detail = $parent.find('.store-detail'); // Find the associated <p> tag
        
        $detail.toggle(); // Toggle the visibility of the <p> tag
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

The `id` of each element is irrelevant here. ID's should be avoided whenever possible because their use creates brittle code that doesn't scale well. Instead, get referenced to elements in a more relative way. That is, find your elements based on where in the DOM structure something is located.

See comments inline.

```js
// Set up one event handler that is an ancestor of all the possibly clicked elements
// and let the event bubble up to it from whichever element within 
// it that was clicked.
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Check to see if the event was triggered by an element we care to handle.
  if(event.target.classList.contains("store-detail-link")){
    // Reference the <p> that comes after the clicked <a>
    $(event.target).next("p").toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <a class="store-detail-link" href="${URLUtils.url('Stores-Details', 'storeID', store.ID)}">
        Details 1
    </a>
    <p class="${store.ID} test">Show/Hide 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="store-detail-link" href="${URLUtils.url('Stores-Details', 'storeID', store.ID)}">
        Details 2
    </a>
    <p class="${store.ID} test">Show/Hide 2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="store-detail-link" href="${URLUtils.url('Stores-Details', 'storeID', store.ID)}">
        Details 3
    </a>
    <p class="${store.ID} test">Show/Hide 3</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Don't *just use* `event.target` per se. The correct logic should be `if (event.target.closest(".store-detail-link")) {`. The way you're advising to use delegation simply does not scale if HTML is modified in the way to introduce child nodes inside the delegator. Also, if makes no sense to block an anchor with a well populated `href` do what's supposed to do. - at least not without asking OP about the real intention of those elements - now made pretty much useless.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agree about blocking the link, but really that is a design flaw in the HTML. The link should not be set up to perform two distinct operations (show/hide and navigate) in the first place. Better would be to have the navigational link in the details area that is shown or hidden. But I didn't want the answer to go off on a tangent, so I left it. As for the delegation, sure, but this is meant to give the OP a sense of how this solution can work. The OP bears some responsibility in adjusting to their specific needs.